# form post not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a form as follows

```
    <form class="form-inline" id="inviteForm" action="http://localhost:8000/team/sendInvitation" method="post">
      <div class="modal fade" id="sendInvite" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Send an invite</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-vertical">
                    <!-- Inviteename Form Input -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inviteename">Name :</label>                        <input class="form-control" required="required" name="inviteename" type="text" id="inviteename">                    </div>
                    <!-- Email Form Input -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email :</label>                        <input class="form-control" required="required" name="email" type="email" id="email">                    </div>

                    <!-- Invitemessage Form Input -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="invitemessage">Message :</label>                        <textarea class="form-control" required="required" name="invitemessage" cols="50" rows="10" id="invitemessage"></textarea>                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"  class="uk-button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" id="sendInvitation"><i class="uk-icon-send"></i> Send Email</a>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</form>
```

and my route is as follows

```
 Route::post('sendInvitation',['uses'=>'TeamsController@sendInvitation','as'=>'invitation.send']);
```

and the UI code is as follows

```
<form class="form-inline" id="inviteForm" action="{{URL::route('invitation.send')}}" method="post">
  @include('admin.teams.partials.sendinvite')
</form>
```

and the controller code is as follows :

```
public function sendInvitation()
    {
        dd(Input::all());
    }
```

I am expecting to see the input values dumped on the screen , but right now nothing is happening.

The include file has the UI for modal dialog.

My question is why is the form not being posted. I am pretty sure I am missing something which is very silly, but if you can point it out for me, it would be praiseworthy.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include the controller's code.

Comment: The controller code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the nested form structure.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

Remove `<form class="form-vertical">` and replace with a normal `<div>` or `<span>`.